# npm command not working/responding

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

I was installed nodejs using,

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

after i did `npm install` to generate `package.json`
 but after that npm doesn't responding. its weird i didnt get any response.

i.e if i received an error can resolve it but it simply return `None`

```
mohideen@mohideen-Latitude-XT3:~$ npm install 
mohideen@mohideen-Latitude-XT3:~$
```

like above... what will be the possible error in this scenario ?

even this too not working,

```
mohideen@mohideen-Latitude-XT3:~$ npm 
mohideen@mohideen-Latitude-XT3:~$
```

tried,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
```

and reinstalled...

Comment: To initialize the `package.json` file you should do `npm init` not `npm install`. As to why it's not working, sorry, but I have no idea. I would also recommend using https://github.com/creationix/nvm.

Comment: i am just saying an example... npm not even working

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 os

Comment: It seems you have to install `npm` as well as `node`. http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: try installing npm also https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Comment: thanks all of your comments..

Answer (score 1):

Updating `nodejs` solved this issue,

**1) Remove nodejs:**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
```

**2) curl latest version:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

**3) install from above:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```